# When should we close the EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am pretty new on the ORM's. I just start to read books and documents about Java Persistence API with Hibernate.

I just wondered, closing EntityManagerFactory is similar with jdbc database connection closing?

Should we close it after every persist/update/delete or not? If we don't close it, will the database connection stay opened?

Comment: If an EM holds Connections how could a Connection remain open if the "host" or "parent" is closed ? Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> I just wondered, closing `EntityManagerFactory` is similar with jdbc database connection closing?

This is not exactly true but closing an `EntityManagerFactory` would be closer to destroying a whole connection pool. If you want to think JDBC connection, you should think `EntityManager`.

> Should we close it after every persist/update/delete or not?

Creating an `EntityManagerFactory` is a pretty expensive operation and should be done once for the lifetime of the application (you `close` it at the end of the application). So, no, you should not close it for each persist/update/delete operation.

The `EntityManagerFactory` is created once for all and you usually get an `EntityManager` per request, which is closed at the end of the request (`EntityManager` per request is the most common pattern for a multi-user client/server application).

> If we don't close it, will the database connection stay opened?

As hinted, it's the `EntityManager` that is actually associated to **a** database connection and closing the `EntityManager` will actually release the JDBC connection (most often, return it to a pool).