# Getting org.hibernate.util.JDBCExce ptionReporter

Tags: hibernate, openjpa, c3p0

I have a web application which is using hibernate and OpenJPA for database connectivity. But when the application is idle for more than 8 hrs I am getting following error in the log file.

`24 Nov 2012 05:54:28 1206290820 [http-8080-20] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExce
ptionReporter  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 118,4
45,988 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 11
8,445,989 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_
timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity
 before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for cli
ent timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true'
to avoid this problem.
24 Nov 2012 05:54:28 1206290820 [http-8080-20] DEBUG org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractE
ntityManagerImpl  - mark transaction for rollback
24 Nov 2012 05:54:28 1206290820 [http-8080-20] ERROR root  - org.hibernate.excep
tion.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query`

I have following persistence.xml entry

`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/lbs?autoReconnect=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1800"/>
            <property name="c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="1810"/>`

In one of other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350483/when-should-we-close-the-entitymanagerfactory)! on Stackoverflow forum they are saying that we should close the EntityManager object everytime.

In my application I am doing following thing for EntityManager

I am creating EntityManager as a singleton class which I am using throughout the application.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

The log entry for c3p0 initialization are:

`INFO  org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`

`INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/lbs?autoReconnect=true`

`INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - Connection properties: {user=****, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}`

`INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - autocommit mode: true`

`WARN  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - Both hibernate-style property 'hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period' and c3p0-style property 'c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod' have been set in hibernate.properties. Hibernate-style property 'hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period' will be used and c3p0-style property 'c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod' will be ignored!`

`INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog  - MLog clients using log4j logging.`

`INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry  - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|1b15828] registered.`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|1b15828] unregistered, in order to be reregistered after update.`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|1b15828] registered.`

`INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@a340a84b [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@454eed4 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|8010fe, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 1800, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@f50d6507 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|1233a8e, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/lbs?autoReconnect=true, properties -> {user=******, password=******, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2ryrhz8rc8xlpn1l7vn76|1b15828, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 1
DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 2
DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 3
DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 4
DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 5`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1148d7f config: [start -> 5; min -> 5; max -> 20; inc -> 3; num_acq_attempts -> 30; acq_attempt_delay -> 1000; check_idle_resources_delay -> 1800000; mox_resource_age -> 0; max_idle_time -> 1800000; excess_max_idle_time -> 0; destroy_unreturned_resc_time -> 0; expiration_enforcement_delay -> 450000; break_on_acquisition_failure -> false; debug_store_checkout_exceptions -> false]`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 5; desired target? 1`

`DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - awaitAvailable(): [unknown]
DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1148d7f [managed: 0, unused: 0, excluded: 0]`

Comment: Hi. Well, you are clearly seeing idle Connections time out. That's a bit surprising given the config that you show -- idle Connections should be expiring after 1800 secs. I suspect you have a configuration problem, that the config you think you have is not the config that's actually in force. c3p0 dumps its config at INFO level on initialization. I'd look for that, and verify that maxIdleTime is 1800 as you mean. Also, if you want an idleConnectionTestPeriod (the configuration of which you've mangled a bit), it should be much, much smaller than maxIdleTime / timeout.

Comment: `@SteveWaldman` I have added the log entry at initialization time for c3p0 in my question above.

Comment: it looks like your maxIdleTime is okay. perhaps the Connection that's timing out is a leaked Connection? Try the c3p0 parameters unreturnedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces to see whether there are Connections that don't get promptly returned to the pool. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients Also, as a failsafe, you might try setting maxConnectionAge (but maxIdleTime really should have been sufficient) Again, see the c3p0 docs http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxConnectionAge

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will make the changes in my application and try to find the rouge connection also I will check the "maxConnectionAge" parameter.